# how to get hint value using Typehead.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-typeahead

I'm using Typehead.js and it's working fine, but I have a special case that I'm not sure how to solve.

I'm using `hint:true` so when the user starts typing the search box gets updated with a hint. If the user presses enter at this point without selecting a match from the list I'm not getting any value in the input field, and I don't know where to get the value of the hint.

This is how I initialise Typehead.js

```
$('#search .typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 2
},
{
    name: 'tags',
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: substringMatcher()
});
```

And this is what I mean by hint. When the user writes `ar` he gets `architecture`.

[image]

But as you can see from the HTML I have no value on the inputs.

```
<input class="typeahead tt-hint" type="text" readonly="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1">
<input class="typeahead tt-input" type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto">
```

Comment: You could solve this problem? I'm trying to do it too

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1159

Answer (score 0):

You add the values from the Javascript code not the html code.

You need to do something like this

```
var key_attributes = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('key'),
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
});
key_attributes.initialize();

  $('.attr-row').last().find('.taginput-key').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 0
  }, {
    name: 'key',
    display: 'key',
    source: key_attributes.ttAdapter()
});
```